# iOS - Parse a different format of date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am an iOS newbie. I am looking to parse a date such as "2012-01-02T00:00:00-05:00" into a "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format. So far I have done the following -

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *xExpDate = expirationDate;
NSString *tempExpDate = [xExpDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
```

I don't quite get what to do after this. Any ideas?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that the date formatter won't handle the `:` character in the timezone field.  So you have to modify the date string before you pass it to the formatter to eliminate that.  This is a fairly standard problem, and there are a half-dozen reasonably good ways to remove the `:` character.  The `T` character, on the other hand, does not need to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  NSString *d = @"2012-01-02T00:00:00-0500";

  NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [inputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
  [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
  NSDate *xExpDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:d];
  NSLog(@"xExpDate: %@", xExpDate);
```

I think your datestring isnt correct, because the zone should havent any ":"

Comment: That is what I am receiving from the server. I don't have any control over it. Is it possible to parse the one in my question?

Comment: Also, using your code I get the date as "xExpDate: 2012-01-02 05:00:00 +0000" which isn't what I am looking for. The time is not 05:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

Change **YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** to **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**

```
NSString *result = [inputFormatter dateFromString:expirationDate];
```

### EDIT

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
[inputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:expirationDate];
NSLog(@"Actual Date: %@", date);

[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *result = [inputFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[inputFormatter release];

NSLog(@"formatted Date: %@", result);
```

Refer **[dateFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** and **[Unicode format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)**.

Comment: how would that make any difference? Till here its working fine for me. I need to eliminate the "-05:00" that is at the end

Comment: The edit still doesn't help me parse my originally specified format